# Updating R version in R-ArcGIS/r-bridge?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, arcgis-10.3, installation, r-bridge

I recently installed the R-ArcGIS bridge, following the steps on the associated [github](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge). I have ArcGIS 10.3, along with both R 3.2 & R 3.3 installed. It is only recognizing the R v3.2 installation, but I need it to recognize R v3.3. I have tried using the 'Update R bindings' Arc tool that comes in the installation, but it only recognizes version 3.2. The current R-version in the registry is 3.3.

Is R-bridge compatible with the newest versions of R?

Has anyone experienced issues changing the associated R version with R-bridge?

Comment: ESRI has a nasty habit of hard-coding the R version. Without digging into the Python code before installing, I do not know that this is a fixable problem. Why do you need to force R 3.3? Is there a package dependency that you are dealing with? You could always force an install of a package into an earlier R version and see if it works. Sometimes R version dependencies are not relevant and a bi-product of CRAN compliance.

Comment: Did you install the 32-bit version of R-3.3? I managed to get the R-ArcGIS bridge going with R-3.3.3 (32-bit) and ArcGIS-10.5 a few weeks back, but as indicated by @JeffreyEvans, it was quite a hassle.

Comment: I had not had the 32 bit version installed. This fixed the issue once I installed it. Thank you!

Comment: I have had correspondence with ESRI over this exact issue and thought they had fixed it. They set up a straw man where you need ArcPro to run R 64-bit but, ArcGIS desktop will only run 32-bit. Due to memory limitations, this is a major issue in running spatial analysis. I complained about the spirit of this limitation and was assured that they had fixed this and that you could now use 64-bit R with ArcGIS Desktop. Apparently they reversed their decision. I would recommend contacting them and calling BS on this. I for one, am pretty angry over this game they are playing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The R-ArcGIS bridge is compatible with newer versions of R. The program did not recognize the newer installation because only the 64-bit R version had been installed, but there was a 32-bit version of 3.2 available so it recognized that. Installing the 32-bit version of 3.3 allowed the program to use the newer version.

Comment: If you downvote do you mind explaining why so I can improve my answer? New Stack Exchange user here that's trying to get better.